# typesafe installation: JDK not installed or found, even if they are

Tags: java, jvm, typesafe

I have JDK (both 1.7.0.3 and 1.8.0) installed. I have added path `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin` or `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0` alternately and also have added system variable `JAVA_HOME` with `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03` or  `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0` respectively.

I have downloaded typesafe activator with play, and extracted it in my `C:\` drive. Then when I try to run it by `activator.bat` or by command `activator ui` from CMD the following error(s) are shown:

```
C:\activator-1.0.13>activator ui
'"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\java.exe" -version 2>&1' is not recognized
as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\javac.exe" -version 2>&1' is not recognized
 as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

A Java JDK is not installed or can't be found.
JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0"

Please go to
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
and download a valid Java JDK and install before running Activator.

If you think this message is in error, please check
your environment variables to see if "java.exe" and "javac.exe" are
available via JAVA_HOME or PATH.
```

I am using MS Windows 7.

Additional information:

```
C:\activator-1.0.13>javac -version
javac 1.8.0

C:\activator-1.0.13>java -version
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)

C:\activator-1.0.13>activator ui
'"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\java.exe" -version 2>&1' is not recognized
as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\javac.exe" -version 2>&1' is not recognized
 as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

A Java JDK is not installed or can't be found.
JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0"

Please go to
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
and download a valid Java JDK and install before running Activator.

If you think this message is in error, please check
your environment variables to see if "java.exe" and "javac.exe" are
available via JAVA_HOME or PATH.
```

Comment: Did you use double quotes in the definition of `JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: Of course not, just `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0` as I have mentioned earlier.

Comment: Doesn't seem your case but `activator.bat` has logic to reject a OpenJDK build, it seems to be expecting `java -version` output to start with "java" string only, not "openjdk".

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having a similar problem on Windows...
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Installing Java to a path without spaces and using that as my JAVA_HOME fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I had two problems, one you mentioned and other was a with HP default declared paths(HP declared some paths for their service by default on initial setup when I bought the laptop). Both solved and then play functions smoothly.

Comment: You have just saved me HOURS!! I wish I can upvote this twice!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
 1. Open a Command Prompt as administrator
 3. Navigate to the folder with activator.bat
 4. Type 'activator ui' without the '
 5. Press enter